# Learning react with a click game, onClick won't fire. I think I'm just passing a prop *called* onClick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-props

The Bit component is supposed to be my clickable, which should be incrementing the state due to my mine function in the Mine component.

```
  function Bit(props) {
        return (
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" onClick={props.onClick} />
  )
}
class Mine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bitCoins: 0,
      clickBonus: 1,
      cps: 1,
    }
  }
  mine() {
    alert('here')
    this.setState({
      bitCoins: this.state.bitCoins + 1
    })
    console.log(this.state.bitCoins);
  }
  render() {
    let status;
    status = this.state.bitCoins
    return (
          <div>
            <Bit onClick={() => this.mine()} />
          </div>
          <div className="text-primary">{status}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried () => props.onClick() in the img element? probably a binding issue...

Comment: That's what ended up doing it:

<Bit onClick={this.mine.bind(this)} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is returned from `render` in React cannot have sibling elements at the top level.  So just wrapping what you're returning with `<React.Fragment>` (or a `div` or whatever else you choose) fixed it.

Also note that `setState` is asynchronous, so when you `console.log` immediately after calling it, you may not get the most up to date values.

```js
class Mine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bitCoins: 0,
      clickBonus: 1,
      cps: 1,
    }
  }
  
  mine() {
    alert('here')
    this.setState({
      bitCoins: this.state.bitCoins + 1
    })
    console.log(this.state.bitCoins);
  }
  
  render() {
    let status;
    status = this.state.bitCoins
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.mine()}>Mine</button>
        </div>
        <div className="text-primary">{status}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Mine />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: "you may not get the most up to date values" this should be "you **will never** get the most up to date values". State is only updated after re-render.